# Automatic hotkey binding for keys "1" to "9" to reassign value of an attribute

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I want to bind keys `1` to `9` (as few as possible) to have each key change the current category in my class.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *


class MyCanvas:
    def __init__(self,
                 categories):
        self.categories = categories
        self._current_category = categories[0]
        self._window = None

        self._main()

    def _main(self):
        master = Tk()
        self._window = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
        self._window.pack()

        self._assign_each_category_to_hotkey()
        mainloop()

    def _assign_each_category_to_hotkey(self):
        for i in range(len(self.categories)):
            self._window.bind(str(i+1), lambda e, c=self.categories[i]: self._change_category(c))

    def _change_category(self, category):
        print(category)
        self._current_category = category


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyCanvas(categories=['tree', 'monster'])
```

I'm expecting the hotkeys "1", "2", etc. to be acceptable.

I expect `tree` or `monster` to print in the console when I press keys 1 or 2 respectively with my sample code above, but nothing seems to happen.

When I run my code, the `_change_category` method doesn't seem to be called. How can I change this?

[full code](https://github.com/jtara1/ManualImageClassification/blob/master/run.py)

Comment: What's your question? Does this code not work as expected? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: @Rawing I updated it to ask a question.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @BryanOakley I updated the sample code provided that illustrates the same problem.